# What is the meaning of (*) in template<typename T> using L = T(*)(T);?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, function-pointers

I've been using this snippet of code for some testing and I understand what it does but it just occured to me I have no idea what `(*)` is supposed to do in this situation...

```
template<typename T>
using L  = T(*)(T);
```

I've tried removing it and the code runs perfectly fine without it. I think it might have something to do with pointers but I am not sure. I use the snippet to define parameters and return value of a passed lambda function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a pointer type. `T(*)(T)` is a pointer to function `T(T)`, which takes `T` and returns `T`.

Without it, i.e. `T(T)` is a function type. You said it works too, because in many cases it could [decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer) to pointer to function as `T(*)(T)`. For example, if you define `T(T)` as the function parameter type, which would be adjusted to `T(*)(T)`.

> An [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) of function type T can be implicitly converted to a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) [pointer to that function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions).

Comment: Oh I think I get it! If I keep the `(*)` I can create function pointers like this `L<int> fp = func;` but If I remove it I can't create it.

Comment: @Buffer Yes, without `(*)` `fp` is declared as a function which can't be initialized like that.